# Java Search Engine Debugging

Tags: java, arrays, search-engine

I run through the entire code. I am able to enter a simple .txt file to search for a word. After it asks for a word, it returns

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -48 at SearchEngine.main(SearchEngine.java:150)

Line 150 is for (int j = 0; j

Any help debugging?

This is basic search engine program that should be able to search a .txt file for any word.

Assignment link: http://cis-linux1.temple.edu/~yates/cis1068/sp12/homeworks/concordance/concordance.html

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class SearchEngine {


    //Counts the number of words in the file
    public static int getNumberOfWords (File f) throws FileNotFoundException {
        int numWords = 0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(f);
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            numWords++;
            scan.next();
        }
        scan.close();

        return numWords;
    }


    public static void readInWords (File input, String[] x) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(input);
        int i = 0;
        while (scan.hasNext() && i < x.length) {
            x[i] = scan.next();
            i++;
        }
        scan.close();
    }

    public static String[] getNumOfDistinctWords (String[] x) throws FileNotFoundException {

        HashSet<String> distinctWords = new HashSet<String>();
        for(int i=0; i<x.length; i++){
            distinctWords.add(x[i]);
        }

        String[] distinctWordsArray = new String[distinctWords.size()];
        int i = 0;
        for(String word : distinctWords){
            distinctWordsArray[i] = word;
            i++;
        }


        return distinctWordsArray;
    }

    public static int getNumberOfLines (File input) throws FileNotFoundException {
        int numLines = 0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(input);
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            numLines++;
            scan.nextLine();
        }
        scan.close();
        return numLines;
    }

    public static void readInLines (File input, String [] x) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(input);
        int i = 0;
        while (scan.hasNextLine() && i<x.length) {
            x[i] = scan.nextLine();
            i++;
        }
        scan.close();
    }



    public static void main(String [] args) {

        try {

            //gets file name
            System.out.println("Enter the name of the text file you wish to search");
            Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
            String fileName = kb.nextLine();
            String TXT = ".txt";
            if (!fileName.endsWith(TXT)) {
                fileName = fileName.concat(TXT);
            }

            File input = new File(fileName);

            //First part of creating index

            System.out.println("Creating vocabArray");
            int NUM_WORDS = getNumberOfWords(input);

            //Output the number of words in the file
            System.out.println("Number of words is: " + NUM_WORDS);


            String[] allWordsArray = new String[NUM_WORDS];
            readInWords(input, allWordsArray);
            Arrays.sort(allWordsArray);
            String[] distinctWordsArray = getNumOfDistinctWords(allWordsArray);

            //Output the number of distinct words
            System.out.println("Number of distinct words is: " + distinctWordsArray.length);
            System.out.println("Finished creating distinctWordsArray");

            System.out.println("Creating concordanceArray");
            int NUM_LINES = getNumberOfLines(input);
            String[] concordanceArray = new String[NUM_LINES];
            readInLines(input, concordanceArray);
            System.out.println("Finished creating concordanceArray");

            System.out.println("Creating invertedIndex");
            int [][] invertedIndex = new int[distinctWordsArray.length][10];
            int [] wordCountArray = new int[distinctWordsArray.length];


            int lineNum = 0;
            while (lineNum < concordanceArray.length) {
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(concordanceArray[lineNum]);

                while (scan.hasNext()) {
                    //Find the position the word appears on the line, if word not found returns a number less than 0
                    int wordPos = Arrays.binarySearch(distinctWordsArray, scan.next());

                    if(wordPos > -1){
                        wordCountArray[wordPos] += 1;
                    }


                    for(int i = 0; i < invertedIndex.length; i++) {
                        for(int j = 0; j < invertedIndex[i].length; j++) {
                            if (invertedIndex[i][j] == 0) {
                                invertedIndex[i][j] = lineNum;
                                break;
                            } 
            }
            }
                }
             lineNum++;
            }
            System.out.println("Finished creating invertedIndex");

        System.out.println("Enter a word to be searched (type quit to exit program)");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String searchWord = keyboard.next();
        while (!searchWord.equals("quit")) {
            int counter = 0;

                        int wordPos = Arrays.binarySearch(allWordsArray, searchWord);
                for (int j = 0; j<invertedIndex[wordPos].length; j++) {
                    if(invertedIndex[wordPos][j] != 0) {
                           int number = invertedIndex[wordPos][j];
                           String printOut = concordanceArray[number];
                                                   System.out.print(number);
                                                   System.out.print(" :");
                                                   System.out.println(printOut);
                                        }
                }

                }        



        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
            System.out.println("File Not Found");
        }

    } //main
} //class
```

Comment: try asking a question about it.  what do you think ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException  means?

Comment: when will they teach unit testing in universities?

Comment: Debuggin ? Really? - what is at line number 150 of your original code ?

Comment: There are two instances of `for (int j = 0; j`, which one is it?

Comment: @ringbearer, it was simple typo.

Comment: @dann.dev  It's the second one. The problem occurs when I search for the actual word in the file. I do not understand why I am getting a -48. I thought binary search either returns a positive number if the search is valid, and a -1 if what you're searching for does not exist. But a -48 does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

`int wordPos = Arrays.binarySearch(allWordsArray, searchWord);`

`wordPos` will be negative when the `searchWord` is not in the array. Therefore,

in `for (int j = 0; j<invertedIndex[wordPos].length; j++) {`, `invertedIndex[wordPos]` will be trying to access a negative index of the array, in your case, `-48`

You should do something like this before the loop:

```
if(wordPos < 0){
  // Do something
}else {
  for (int j = 0; j<invertedIndex[wordPos].length; j++) {
  ...
}
```

You should read the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%29), specially the doc for `returns`. You will get your answer about `-48`.